# Passing arguments to ES6 class module in SystemJS

Tags: ecmascript-6, systemjs

I am experimenting with SystemJS and have run into some problems when trying to pass arguments to my exported Class.

Inlined into my html I have the following:

```
<script>
    System.import('modules/accordion.js').then(function(module){
        module.accordion('HELLO THERE');
    });
</script>
```

The accordion.js file contains the following class:

```
class Accordion {
    constructor(message) {
        this.message = message;
        this.buildAccordion();
    }
    buildAccordion() {
        console.log(this.message);
    }
}

export var accordion = new Accordion();
```

This file is pre-transpiled with babel before being imported by SystemJS.

The resulting console log contains `undefined`. How do i properly pass the arguments to this function?

Comment: You cannot do anything with it - the `Accordion` object was instantiated with `message` equals to `undefined`. "to this function" --- to *what* function? `module.accordion` if not even a function, but an object.

Answer (score 0):

@zerkms pointed out that the when the class was being instantiated message was `undefined`.

When I call the class from the import callback the message is then properly passed. So now the accordion file looks like this:

```
export class Accordion {
    constructor(message) {
        this.message = message;
        this.buildAccordion();
    }
    buildAccordion() {
        console.log(this.message);
    }
}
```

And my inline script looks like:

```
<script>
    System.import('modules/accordion.js').then(function(module){
        var accordion = new module.Accordion('HELLO THERE');
    });
</script>
```

Now I get `HELLO THERE` printed in the console. :)